# Running MongoDB query against already pulled data in Go

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a Golang application exposing web services and using MongoDB as a backend database. It has 2 relevant collections:

- customers - contains documents with nested structures
- filters - contains stored Mongo search queries for data in customers collection

I want to implement a use-case, where given 1 document from customers collection, I want to see which filters match this given customer document.

The easiest way I could think of is to run each filter query against a customers collection, but in case there's hundreds of stored filters, this could be inefficient.

The solution I found was to implement such filtering myself in application, but I keep this as a last resort. So is there a way to do this sort of check "offline" in application, without having to implement all supported Mongo search queries?

Comment: Hi there, please share source code to reproduce your issue~

Comment: I don't exactly have an issue or code to show something, but rather I'm asking for pointers on how to efficiently implement the use-case described above using MongoDB and Go programming language.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

1. Preprocess the results by running each filter against the customers collection, then storing the results filter-customer mapping in a third collection.
2. At query time, when you are given a customer document, fetch the preprocessed result from the third collection. That's all filters that matched that customer.
3. Whenever you update the customer collection, you have to redo the preprocessing in the background. You can narrow the scope to the impacted documents to improve performance (using an additional filter on impacted IDs for example).

**Long Answer**

The problem statement is generic a little bit. Maybe with some constraints, more solutions will be more viable:

- What is the size of the customers collection? How frequently does it change? Are documents updated individually or in batches?
- What is the size of the filters collection? How frequently does it change? Are documents updated individually or in batches?
- Any constraints on result consistency?
- How is the filters collection constructed? Are those historic queries or something else?

The solution described above would work fine if both collections are mutated with a low frequency (i.e. few times a day). With preprocessing, you will have a small latency at query time, but data might be inconsistent if a query happens while preprocessing is running (however, it will be eventually consistent).

Implementing filtering in the application is plausible if the filters are not too complex and it's okay to start with a few operators instead of implementing all operators which might be too much. This will be highly customizable and can be tuned to maximize performance.

Another idea is that if the filters are historic queries, then it will be more efficient to store the customer IDs post-querying. This will eliminate the preprocessing work.

One more idea is that if the documents are updated individually (no batch operations), then there is room to optimize preprocessing. For each filter, keep track of which fields impact the result (e.g. a filter `{"name": "john"}` is impacted by the name field only). Whenever a document is updated, decide on the filters that need to be recomputed. This is more of a heuristic that will tell you which filters will be definitely a match, no match, or recomputation required based on the updated fields.

So basically, it all depends on how and when data comes in, and accordingly, one solution (or a combination of solutions) will be more efficient than the others.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the pointer, that's quite a good idea. I'll try to work on this a bit more to suit my environment. Just to answer some of your questions:
- customers collection can change ad any time, on per-document basis (no batch updates)
- customers collection can contain tens of millions documents
- filters collection can contain hundreds to low thousands of filters
- filters in collection are created by business user, they are not historic queries
- ideally the change in filter or customer data should be reflected in real-time, but some variant of your idea could work too